# How can I get data from MySQL via Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to get some data via Ajax, but there must be some mistake because the result is empty

script:

```
<script>
function showUser(value) {
    var values = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        data: {
            id: value
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    })

}
</script>
```

html:

```
<form>
    <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select a person:</option>
        <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
        <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
        <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
        <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
$id = @$_POST['id'];

$pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = "' . $id . '"');

while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo  $row['id'];
}     

?>
```

Comment: `data: {
            id: value
        },`    I think it should be `data: {
            id: values
        },`

Comment: changed it, thank you. But still do not get a result

Comment: the mistake must be in the `data` because if I `alert(data);` then it is empty

Comment: @TomaszBarański I found out that my mistake was in the database connection!

Comment: @TomaszBarański Hm, but still do not have any results...

Comment: Ah now I changed back "values" to "value" and it is working!

Comment: The error suppression operator `@` is probably not the best idea. It may actually hide useful errors. If you're worried about showing errors to the user in a production environment then you should alter your _php.ini_ file to suppress errors globally.

Comment: @Jarla  check the answers below and i hope they will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***HTML:-***

```
<select id ="myselect" name="users" onchange="showUser()">
      <option value="">Select a person:</option>
      <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
      <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
      <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
      <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

***Javascript:-***

```
<script>
    function showUser() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            data: {
                id: $( "#myselect option:selected" ).val();
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

***PHP:-***

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        // i don't know from where $db is coming so check yourself

        $pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM people WHERE id = "'.$id.'" LIMIT 1'); 
        while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $row['id'];
        } 
    }else{
       echo "Please select value from select box";
    }                             
    ?>
```

Note:-

***Meanwhile read about `prepared statements` and use them to prevent from `SQL Injection`. Thanks***

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use jquery, you can do something like this:-

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "****Some URL (php etc to process the sql data)******";
var p = hex_sha512(userPass.value);
var params = "email="+userEmail.value+"&p="+p+"&adminStat=true";

http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.send(params);

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        //Todo
        // check addition stat and go to the destination page
        if (http.responseText == "success") {
            window.location = "*****Destination URL********";
        } else {
            alert("error");
        }
    }
};
```